# Why still in Fragment A although already navigate to Fragment B Navigation Component?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I have 2 fragment, `LoginFragment` and `SignUpFragment`.When in `SignUpFragment`, click on Android back button at the bottom,it navigate to `LoginFragment`.

This is the code for doing so:

**SignUpFragment.java**

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            @Override
            public void handleOnBackPressed() {
                NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(view);
                navController.popBackStack(R.id.signUpFragment,true);
                navController.navigate(R.id.loginFragment);
            }
        });
}
```

So this work as expected,I can go back to `LoginFragment.java` when click the back button in `SignUpFragment.java`.

**Problem:**

The problem now is,when I in `LoginFragment`,I click on the Android back button at the bottom again,I having this error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: View android.widget.RelativeLayout{3be3bdc V.E...... ......ID 0,0-1080,1962 #7f0a017d app:id/root_layout} does not have a NavController set
    at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.java:84)
    at com.company.ui.user.SignUpFragment$3.handleOnBackPressed(SignUpFragment.java:128) //WHY THIS LINE??
    at androidx.activity.OnBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed(OnBackPressedDispatcher.java:189)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onBackPressed(ComponentActivity.java:286)
```

As you can see,the error shown is said the error cause by `handleOnBackPressed(SignUpFragment.java:128)`,means that it caused by `handleOnBackPressed()` function inside `SignUpFragment.java`.

But in reality I click the back button when I in `LoginFragment.java`.And inside `LoginFragment.java` doesnt have any `handleOnBackPressed()` function.

I totally having no idea why this behavior could happened?.

**Question:**

Why is this could happened? What causing this?? And how to solve this??

Comment: Can't your `navigation.xml` handle the backpress normally ? Are you sure you need to create a custom `backpress` ?

Comment: @Biscuit ya I need custom `onBackPressed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
> ```

Should be

```
requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try and replace your piece of code by this one :

```java
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    navController = Navigation.findNavController(view);

    requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(getViewLifecycleOwner(), () -> {
           navController.popBackStack(R.id.signUpFragment,true);
           navController.navigate(R.id.loginFragment);
    });
```

EDIT: Change code as per accepted answer, and give the full code.

Comment: bro I cant `addOnBackPressedCallback` is cant resolved